# Improve FrameServer performances

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding, live, performance, live-performance

I followed ffmpeg guide to install debugmode frameserver.

All works fine except with the fact that the frames served does not goes up to 25 fps. FFmpeg reports a speed of 0.9x..

My initial goal would have been use ffmpeg for encode very fast instead using native NLE export..

I would have expected something like 50x ! How can I improve the performances of the frameserver? The signpost avi is on a NVME professional drive.

There are other frameservers compatible with AviSynth that I can use instead of the debugmode one?

The string I used is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i D:\frameserver_test\frameserver.avs -map 0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 3000k -c:a copy D:\frameserver_test\out.mov
```

while frameserver.avs contains:

```
AviSource("D:\frameserver_test\output.avi");
```

Comment: What's your command?

Comment: @Gyan what do you mean for my command? The ffmpeg command that I cast for prepare the final file, avysinth or something related to the frameserver ?

Comment: The ffmpeg command?

Comment: @Gyan I edited the question and added the command line, thanks

Comment: What's the speed for `ffmpeg -y -i D:\frameserver_test\frameserver.avs -map 0 -c copy -f null -`